# Increase nginx response timeout

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I have ngnix server that proxies incoming requests to a docker that has another ngnix running and it forwards requests to a nodejs server. Sometime my nodejs server takes upto 10-15 minutes to respond with a reply. But before nodejs server responds, I get `502 Bad Gateway`. I tried to increase ngnix timeout on both the ngnix servers one on the host machine and another on the docker, but it does not seem to work

```
client_header_timeout  15m;
client_body_timeout    15m;
send_timeout           15m;
proxy_read_timeout 15m;
proxy_connect_timeout 15m;
```

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_connect_timeout `It should be noted that this timeout cannot usually exceed 75 seconds.`

Comment: @AlexeyTen that's sad. What if something takes more than 75 seconds, is there no way we can use ngnix there

Comment: related https://serverfault.com/questions/571614/why-cant-nginx-have-more-than-75-seconds-proxy-connect-wait/571672